# Проблема с загрузкой файлов различных форматов из Firebase Storage

Tags: android, firebase, download

Загружаются файлы в папку приложения Android/data/com.android.../files/

Но загружаются файлы неизвестного типа. Но открыть файлы в нужном формате можно, если знать формат. Как можно это исправить?

Код загрузки файла:

```
private void downloadDoc(String name, String ref) {
    File localFile = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null), name);
    final File finalLocalFile = localFile;
    downloadRef = storage.getReferenceFromUrl(ref);
        downloadRef.getFile(localFile).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                Toast.makeText(DocumentationActivity.this, finalLocalFile.getPath().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(DocumentationActivity.this, "Fail", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
}
```

Пробовал добавить во 2 строчку тип файла:

```
File localFile = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null), name + ".doc");
```

Файлы .doc работают нормально, как и следовало ожидать. Но у меня различные файлы присутствуют в Firebase Storage. Как добиться того, чтобы файлы сохранялись со своим форматом?

P.S. Находил примеры только при работе с изображениями, не помогли.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте сохранять и вытаскивать мета данные content typee, 
https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/file-metadata

- setContentType
- getContentType

Скорее всего в формате MIME.

Comment: Спасибо. А не подскажете, как грамотно присвоить это файлу? Или проверять через условие и подставлять к имени заранее подготовленный формат?

Comment: Давайте посмотрим на код или процедуру загрузки файлов в Storage.

Comment: Код, который добавляет метаданные перед загрузкой в Storage?
`StorageMetadata metadata = new StorageMetadata.Builder()
        .setContentType("image/jpg")
        .build();`

Comment: Соответственно после загрузки вам надо присвоить это к ref файла

Comment: у меня файлы изначально там лежат

Comment: Тогда попробуйте по ним проитерировать и в листенере на референс присвоить метадату.